# Word "infamous" - bad or good meaning

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, vocabulary

According to dictionary:

```
adjective
    well known for some bad quality or deed.
```

But sometimes I see news or people say:

- infamous [person]
- infamous [movie]
- ...

and I checked these person or movie don't have bad manners or bad quality at all, and it sounds to me "infamous" in these cases more positive (or I am wrong). So should I understand "infamous" with a negative meaning?

**EDIT**: For example, one video went viral about a dad having an interview at home and his toddler broke into the room, it was funny, and the event was harmless (I guess). And now I am reading this article: 
[It’s Been Exactly 12 Months Since The Infamous BBC Dad On-Air Blooper](https://www.pedestrian.tv/entertainment/bbc-dad-twelve-months-on/). If according to dictionary, then it means bad deed. But this event went viral and peope loved it.

Comment: Even words like *bad* can be used in a positive way in certain contexts. Please post and link to some actual examples so we can see what you’re looking at.

Comment: @Lawrence I posted one example

Comment: Even if it was harmless and funny, the toddler interrupting a serious interview was unprofessional and not the sort of thing a broadcaster wants to happen, so you could say it was famous for the wrong reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without examples we can't be sure what you've read, but I'd guess the construction wasn't "...the infamous film Star Wars...", but "Star Wars is infamous for...".

In other words, there is a famously bad aspect to the film that is being picked out, not the whole film. For example [in this article](https://beaveronline.co.uk/star-wars-last-jedi-top-three-theories/) there is the sentence:

> But Star Wars is infamous for having misdirects in their trailers.

The author isn't saying that this particular Star Wars film is infamous, but that the Star Wars series are famous for having misleading aspects to their trailers and that the author perceives this as being bad.